# How can I fix the PyQt5 platfrom plugin error?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I started to learn PyQt5 and I downloaded PyQt5 via pip (pip install PyQt5 and pip install PyQt5 tools)
I have no problem with designer, so I can open the designer but when I try to write and run PyQt5 code I got this error:

**This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.**

My Code:

```
import PyQt5

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QToolTip
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QMainWindow()

    win.setWindowTitle('First Application')
    win.setGeometry(200,200,500,500)
    win.setToolTip('my tooltip')

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

Note: I use python IDLE

Comment: try add `import PyQt5` `import os` `dirname = os.path.dirname(PyQt5.__file__)`
`plugin_path = os.path.join(dirname, 'Qt5', 'plugins', 'platforms')` `os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH"] = plugin_path` before `def window():`

Comment: also execute: `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS="1" python /path/of/script.py`

Comment: i added but i still got same error also how can i execute QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS="1" python /path/of/script.py

Comment: Open the CMD or console and run this command

Comment: i got this error: 'QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: okay, add `os.environ["QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS"] = "1"` before `def window():` and execute `python /path/of/script.py`

Comment: I got this result: [link](https://imgur.com/3rH9ey4)

Comment: i finally fix the error and now i can run my pyqt apps